# Countable union of cartesian product.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $I^1_j$ $1$-dimensional intervals( of the form $[a,b)$) and $I^n_j$ be $n$-dimensional interval(of the form $[a_1,b_1)\times \ldots\times [a_n,b_n)$) such that $I_j\times I^n_j$ are pairwise disjoint, suppose that $\displaystyle\bigcup_{j \in \Bbb N}I^1_j\times I^n_j=I$ (union is disjoint)is an $(n+1)$-dimensional interval.

Can we say $$\bigcup_{j \in \Bbb N}I^1_j\times I^n_j=I=\bigcup_{j\in \Bbb N}I^1_j \times \bigcup_{j\in \Bbb N}I^n_j \text{  ?}$$

The only thing I figured out is that the RHS unions are not necessarily disjoint.

Comment: So you are asking if $\bigcup(A_i\times B_i)=\bigcup A_i\times\bigcup B_i$? The answer is no.

Comment: I guess it is not true in a general setting, but I am asking if it holds in the case above. A proof I am reading uses it, but changes the indices. Might it be that $\bigcup(A_i\times B_i)=\bigcup A_k\times\bigcup B_l$?

Comment: I do have a problem with the fact that the union of disjoint cubes is an interval. That part doesn't make sense to me. Is it open, or closed, or neither?

Comment: Thanks for the note, I edited that in. I don't mean that the union of such intervals is always an interval, it happens that union of these intervals happens to be an interval.

Comment: It's never an interval. What you en up with looks like stairways.

Comment: Not necessarily, $[a,b) \cup [b,c)=[a,c)$

Comment: @leo , this comes from trying to prove Lebesgue measure is countably additive on the semi-ring of half open intervals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the specific situation in the question, we have the equality

$$\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} (I_j^1\times I_j^n) = I = \left(\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} I_j^1\right)\times \left(\bigcup_{j\in\mathbb{N}} I_j^n\right)$$

provided that none of the $I_j^1$ or $I_j^n$ are empty. If some $I_j^1$ or $I_j^n$ are empty, the product on the right could be a proper superset of $I$.

That these are intervals is irrelevant, as is the countability of the union or the fact that the union on the left is disjoint.

All that matters is that we have two families $\{ X_\alpha : \alpha \in A\}$ and $\{ Y_\alpha : \alpha \in A\}$ of nonempty sets, indexed by the same index set, and

$$\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} (X_\alpha \times Y_\alpha) = \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}.$$

Then we also have

$$\bigcup_{\alpha \in A} X_\alpha = \mathcal{X}\tag{x}$$

and

$$\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} Y_\alpha = \mathcal{Y},\tag{y}$$

and therefore

$$\left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} X_\alpha\right) \times \left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} Y_\alpha\right) = \mathcal{X}\times \mathcal{Y}.\tag{p}$$

Since we assumed all $Y_\alpha \neq \varnothing$, we have $\pi_1(X_\alpha\times Y_\alpha) = X_\alpha$ for all $\alpha$, and hence $(\text{x})$:

$$\mathcal{X} = \pi_1(\mathcal{X}\times\mathcal{Y}) = \pi_1 \left(\bigcup_{\alpha\in A} (X_\alpha\times Y_\alpha)\right) = \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} \pi_1(X_\alpha\times Y_\alpha) = \bigcup_{\alpha\in A} X_\alpha.$$

The assumption $X_\alpha\neq\varnothing$ for all $\alpha$ yields $(\text{y})$ in the same way, using the projection $\pi_2$ to the second factor.